# Firefox CSS error (Works fine in Chrome)

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have come across a problem, the below code works fine in Chrome however it doesn't in Firefox.

```html
<div id="client-controls">
<p style="margin-left: -90px;"><b>DHCP (?)</b></p>
<input type="checkbox" name="uncheckdhcp" id="uncheckdhcp" onclick="return uncheckdhcp();" checked/>
```

```css
#client-controls html {
    background-color: #e4ded4;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,0%,.1), hsla(0,0%,100%,.1));
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
    height: 100%;
}
#client-controls input[type="checkbox"] {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,0%,.1), hsla(0,0%,100%,.1)),
                      -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f66 50%, #088A08 50%);
    background-size: 100% 100%, 200% 100%;
    #background-position: 0 0, 15px 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px hsla(0,0%,0%,.5),
                inset 0 0 10px hsla(0,0%,0%,.5),
                0 0 0 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.1),
                0 -1px 2px 2px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25),
                0 2px 2px 2px hsla(0,0%,100%,.75);
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;
    left: 0%;
    #margin: -12px -37px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    #position: left;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -20%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 80px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-transition: .25s;
align:left;
float:left;
}
#client-controls input[type="checkbox"]:after {
    background-color: #eee;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.1), hsla(0,0%,0%,.1));
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,1),
                inset 0 -1px 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25),
                0 1px 3px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.5),
                0 0 2px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25);
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    #position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 25px;
}
#client-controls input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background-position: 0 0, 80px 0;
    padding-left: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    content-align: left;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Please can someone let me know where I am going wrong, and perhaps what needs changing?

PS: This code is for a sliding toggle button, it displays in chrome, FF shows just a checkbox with the shadow background.
Thankyou.

Comment: You shouldn't add a *code snippet* when you aren't actually showing any output. With CSS alone, the snippet won't display anything. Therefore it's useless and you should've only used the code-tags, not the snippet. Even better: use the snippet option, but add some HTML to show the problem. Now we have to guess where things go wrong. (But as the answer suggests, it's probably due to vendor prefixes - and possibly also because you do some strange things such as `#position: left`.)

Comment: Your code example is full of errors. Anyway, you'll need to provide us with some HTML to go with the CSS to give us an idea of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Pseudo elements can't be used on form inputs. `#client-controls input[type="checkbox"]:after` this line shouldn't work in any browser. Edit: you can wrap the checkbox in a container and use pseudo elements on that div.

Comment: Hi guys, the html is above, I've updated the main post.

Comment: All those `-webkit-` styles... that `-webkit-` part means that it only works in Webkit browsers. Firefox is not a Webkit browser, so none of them will work. Remove the `-webkit-` parts and make sure you're using the correct standard format for the style, and you should find your code working much better across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding -moz prefixes where you have -webkit prefixes?

Comment: It appears that it works with that, it's just the grey toggle which doesn't appear.

Comment: Anyone who can addon to what Mike said?